# Dynamic text color changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, jquery-animate

I have written this code for dynamic color changing of text. Function works fine, but problem is that there is a recursion. After call I have js "too much recursion" error. Is there a possibility, or another solution to do this without any problem?

```
function dynamicColor() {
        $(".class").animate({
            color: 'rgb(255,40,80)'
        }, 1000).animate({
            color: 'rgb(100,255,40)'
        }, 1000).animate({
            color: 'rgb(40,100,255)'
        }, 1000).animate({
            color: 'rgb(255,40,100)',
            complete: dynamicColor()
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not assigning a reference, you keep calling it

```
complete: dynamicColor()
```

needs to be

```
complete: dynamicColor
```

or

```
complete: function() { dynamicColor(); }
```

Next issue is you have complete inside of the properties you are animating. It is not going to be called.

```js
function dynamicColor() {
    $(".class").animate({height: "100px"}, 1000)
               .animate({height: "200px"}, 1000)
               .animate({height: "300px"}, 1000)
               .animate({height: "200px"},{duration: 1000,complete: dynamicColor});
}

dynamicColor();
```

```css
.class {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class">This is a test</div>
```

Comment: When I'm doing this like that, function doesn't make recursion